# Java-Assign string within array to JButton randomly within a for loop. Each element once

Tags: arrays, string, random, jbutton, unique

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     String[] word = {" The ", " itsy " , " bitsy ", " spider ", " went " , " up " , 
                      " the ", " water ", " spout. ", " Down ", " came ", " the " , 
                      " rain ", " and ", " flushed ", " the ", " spider ", " out. "};
     Random random = new Random();

     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frame.setTitle("JavaGame");
     frame.setSize(600,600);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     JPanel northPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,6));
     for (int i=0; i<18; i++) {
         JButton button = new JButton();
         northPanel.add(button);
         button.setText(word[random.nextInt(word.length)]);
     }
}
```

I'm looking for something to plug in to make sure each element only populates once.

Comment: What is your question? What did you input? What's wrong with the result?

Comment: Please clearly state your question, which I suspect is "How do I use each element of the array to make a button in random order?"

Comment: My code will already randomly assign one of the strings in the array to a jbutton. However, it doesn't use all the elements. I just want to assign each element in the array to each one of the 18 jbuttons once.

Comment: So im using a for loop that'll generate 18 jbuttons and a string array with 18 elements. My code randomly assigns one of the elements to a jbutton as intended. However, I want each element to be used only once. Rather than the randomizer assigning 5 of the same elements to 5 different JButtons. Yes, i realize some of my elements are in fact the same. The code above generates " the itsy bitsy spider"